# What is the file extension for graphql queries?

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphql

since graphql queries are text, I'd like to just store them in a separate file, but I'm not finding any language support. `gql` files are for schema, not queries.

What's the vs code support for graphql queries?

- What file extension is the convention if one is going to store queries in a file?
- Is query syntax highlighting / intellisense (based on schema) possible?
- can I `import` the query?
  What I tried:

I put the query in a .gql file, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file extension is `.graphql` and the loading can be handled by WebPack.

[documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/integrations/webpack/)

Comment: "This is the way". Thanks for the great answer. I'm assuming `graphql-tag` answers my third question bullet point, and `Apollo GraphQL` extension for VS Code handles the syntax highlighting. I'll check it out. (I realize Apollo is so much more than ide support; that's just the vs code extension). I'll mark as answer when the checkbox becomes available.